# How do you select a specific field and star in a DB2 query?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to view all columns in a DB2 database query however I want to put a certain column at the front.

For example from my sql knowledge I would write something like

```
SELECT Field2, * FROM Table
```

However the above query is returning an error like below

```
SQL State: 42601
Vendor Code: -104
Message: [SQL0104] Token * was not valid. Valid tokens: ( + - ? : DAY INF NAN RID ROW RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS HASH. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token *.
Token * is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is ( + - ? : DAY INF NAN RID ROW RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS HASH.
This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.
The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :
Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token *.
Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses.
-- If the error token is <END-OF-STATEMENT>, correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.

Processing ended because the highlighted statement did not complete successfully
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a correlation name, like so:

```
SELECT Field1, tbl.* FROM YourTable tbl
```

Obviously, `tbl.*` returns all columns, so `Field1` will appear twice in the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a view as below;

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "select * from mytable"

VAL NEW_VAL
--- -------
5   -      
6   -      
A   -      

  3 record(s) selected.

user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "CREATE VIEW MYTABLEVW AS SELECT NEW_VAL,VAL FROM MYTABLE"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "select * from mytablevw"

NEW_VAL VAL
------- ---
-       5  
-       6  
-       A  

  3 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this. It would work but adds a bit of overhead for what I need. See @mustaccio's answer which is a bit easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid, you'll have to select each column separately. like

```
select field_you_want_to_appear_first, field2, filed3.. from yourtable
```